# Drawing ellipse filling dataframe with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I need to modify one of my template scripts to draw a circle from the centre of the (inset) data frame to the edge of the data frame. This will then be used to clip the data frame to shape. I'm using ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: I'm guessing your template scripts are written in Python, but could you confirm this please?

Comment: Hi om_henners, yes the script is written in Python (beginner level)